# convert all worksheets of a xlsx to csv with python openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, csv, xlsx, openpyxl

Hi I want I have a xlsx with different worksheets. 
I want to convert the values of every sheet in a new csv with openpyxl. The filename of the new csv should have the name of the sheet.

I did not find out how to convert all of the sheets.... 'just the active sheet'

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile I created a working solution for it:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import openpyxl
import csv

wb = load_workbook(filename='C:\\example.xlsx')

sheetnames = wb.get_sheet_names()
sheet_value_arr = []


for a in sheetnames:
    sheet = wb[a]
    with open('C:\\example_'+ a +'.csv', 'w') as f:
    c = csv.writer(f)
    for row in sheet.rows:
        sheet_value_arr.append([cell.value for cell in row])
        for r in sheet.rows:
            c.writerow([cell.value for cell in row])

f.close()
```

Comment: This code is incorrect. The innermost for-loop is unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

I found a code but it dont convert all sheets:

```
import openpyxl
import csv

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
sh = wb.get_active_sheet()
f = open('example.csv', 'w')

c = csv.writer(f)
for r in sh.rows:
    c.writerow([cell.value for cell in r])
```